# How do i get my pie chart visualisation to show original categorical values?

Tags: machine-learning, data-science, visualization, exploratory-data-analysis

I am using https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/mohamedafsal007/house-price-dataset-of-india/ to visualise the condition of house into a piechart

```
c = df['condition_of_the_house']

explode = [0.1] * len(df.condition_of_the_house.value_counts(),)
explode[0]=0.2                          

plt.pie(df.condition_of_the_house.value_counts(),labels=df.condition_of_the_house.unique(),
explode=explode,autopct="%1.1f%%")
 plt.title('Condition of the house')
 plt.legend()
 plt.show()
```

It showed bad,good etc:- at one point but now it shows 1,2,3,4,5 how do i get the previous format back

Answer (score 0):

In the house price dataset, the values in the "condition of the house" column are integer values [1,2,3,4,5]. When you plot these values on a pie chart, the default labels for the wedges are going to be these integer values.

You can overwrite this default behavior and use your custom labels by providing a list of labels while plotting the pie chart, like the code sample below

```
plt.pie(df.condition_of_the_house.value_counts(),labels=['Poor', 'Below Average', 'Average', 'Above Average', 'Excellent'],
explode=explode,autopct="%1.1f%%")
```